# Prestashop 1.4.9: An account is already registered with this e-mail

Tags: prestashop

I reported a bug in prestashop community at http://forge.prestashop.com/browse/PSCFI-6967 yesterday. Do anybody suggest me any fix for it?

Answer (score 0):

Well since you haven't posted minor version, I've took the first and the last minor versions and diffed them (Customer.php class to be precise).

This is *1.4.0.1*:

```
static public function customerExists($email, $return_id = false)
{
    if (!Validate::isEmail($email))
        die (Tools::displayError());

    $result = Db::getInstance()->getRow('
    SELECT `id_customer`
    FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'customer`
    WHERE `email` = \''.pSQL($email).'\'');

    if ($return_id)
        return intval($result['id_customer']);
    else
        return isset($result['id_customer']);
}
```

And this is *1.4.8.3*:

```
public static function customerExists($email, $return_id = false, $ignoreGuest = true)
{
    if (!Validate::isEmail($email))
        die (Tools::displayError());

    $result = Db::getInstance()->getRow('
    SELECT `id_customer`
    FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'customer`
    WHERE `email` = \''.pSQL($email).'\''
    .($ignoreGuest ? 'AND `is_guest` = 0' : ''));

    if ($return_id)
        return (int)($result['id_customer']);
    else
        return isset($result['id_customer']);
}
```

The thing is, that you are using something in between these two and closer to the lower one.

As you can see the later one has another optional parameter $ignoreGuest which defaults to true. Hence every validation is bypassed.

You can do either one of these two things:

- Upgrade to the latest version of 1.4 (http://code.google.com/p/prestashop/downloads/detail?name=prestashop_1.4.8.3.zip&can=2&q=) if any of your components are not compatible with 1.5. If they are - go all the way to the latest.
- If on the other hand you just need a quick and dirty fix: change the function in Customer class to the second one in this answer.

Comment: Hi povilasp, thank you for your answer. I just edited my question title. I'm using 1.4.9 and the function "customerExists" looks like the second one you provided above. The similar issue here http://forge.prestashop.com/browse/PSCFV-7023